# Visual Studio Tests Build Step Cant find dlls

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, msbuild, build-automation

Hi I have the following Build steps in my TFS build process

1) Build Code 
2) Run Tests

Step one has the following inputs

**Solution** : MyApp\TestApp*.sln

**MSBuild Arguments** : /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl="D:\output"

Then In Step my test step I have the following

Test Assembly : D:\output\bin*tests*.dll

When i run it i get the following warning
**"No test assemblies found matching the pattern: 'D:\output\bin*tests*.dll'**

All the binaries are there except the test project how do I tell step one to publish the test dll's as well? is this the correct way to do it as I am hard coding a path is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

It was because I was building in Release mode and the unit test project was not set to build in release mode